# Ionic Framework 'Error: socket hang up' when trying to use 'ionic upload'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

So when I'm trying to upload my ionic application by using:

```
$ ionic upload
```

I receive the following error:

```
Saved app_id, writing to ionic.io.bundle.min.js...
An error occurred uploading the build: Error: socket hang up

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:202:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:287:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)

socket hang up (CLI v1.7.16)
```

What could be the cause of that?

Extra information:

- Running on Ubuntu 16.04
- Sometimes works, just gotta run the command around 10 times until it doesn't give that error.